# Use socket.io to display realtime data

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I have a .csv file. Each line in the csv file contains fields of text and date (also ordered by date). By iterating the csv file, we count the word frequency of each date and send the word frequency to the client side and display them using html.

I'm using Python3, Flask and Flask-SocketIO, however only the word frequency of the last date is displayed. The debug information can be seen in [Pastebin LINK](http://pastebin.com/ZBskqfxf). From the debug information, it seems SocketIO keeps emitting events without receiving any data on client side until the iteration ends. What I want is emitting and receiving each data during the iteration so I can update the word frequency in real time on client side. Did I do something wrong in using the SocketIO?

Thanks for any suggestions.

For the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //connect to the socket server.
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' +     location.port + '/test');

    //receive details from server
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.emit('my_event', {data: 'I\'m connected!'});
    });

    socket.on('new_count', function(msg) {
        console.log("Received count");
        //get data
        var tags = msg.data;
        console.log(tags[0].key);
        numbers_string = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++){
            numbers_string = numbers_string + '<p>' + tags[i].key + ': ' +    tags[i].value + '</p>';
        }
        $('#vis').html(numbers_string);
        socket.emit("my_event", {data: "one update received!"});
    });
});
```

for the Python code:

```
day=""
@socketio.on('connect', namespace="/test")
def test_connect():
    global day
    print("clinet connected")
    with open("static/sorted_examples.csv", 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        day = ""
        words = []
        for row in reader:
            text = row['text']
            date_day = row['date_day']
            words += text.split()
            if date_day != day:
                day = date_day
                word_count = Counter(words).most_common(20)
                words[:] = []
                emit_data = [dict([("key", k), ("value", v)]) for k, v in word_count]
                socketio.emit('new_count', {"data": emit_data}, namespace='/test')
```

Comment: Withnthat code Flask will emit one message per line in the CVS in a short time. On the JavaScript side you are updating the HTML per mesage overwriting the previous updates. As a result you will see the change of the last message only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer assumes you are using eventlet or gevent, which implement cooperative multitasking.

The `emit()` call works asynchronously, which means that under eventlet or gevent you need to release the CPU if you want it to be processed immediately by the appropriate background threads.

And this is actually very simple, just add a `socketio.sleep(0)` right after the `emit()`. If you find that that impacts performance too much, you can opt to sleep every other loop iteration or more. Basically you need to find the right balance.

Comment: Thanks! I found that put scoketio.sleep() before the emit() works for me! I don't know why, it doesn't work when put it right after emit().